# XSLT: SHOW trailing zeros

Tags: xml, xslt, zero

I have a decimal variable defined in XSD which for example can contain the values 1,5; 1,50; 1,550; 1,500; ...so, it can have an unknown number of decimals, even consisting of zeros.
Now I have written an XSLT (2.0) and will execute with Saxon.

The problem is that I want to show the value in the XML 'as is', with the only difference that I want to use the correct, language dependent decimal separator.

The format-number option only allows me to use the characters (# or 0), whether removing trailing zeros, or in the latter case 'hard-coding' the number of zeros....

Is there any option available allowing me to do what I need, without needing to fall back to String replacements of the decimal separator, since I feel this would be a serious shortage in the format-number function?

Answer (score 1):

Write a function to create a format-number format for you, that takes into account the number of decimal places used in the original value.

```
format-number(., concat('###,###.', substring('0000000000000', 1, concat(string-length(substring-after(., ','))))), euro)
```

Use a decimal format for the language dependend formatting:

```
<xsl:decimal-format name="euro" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="."/>
```